# How can I remove wood that blocks window operation?

Tags: bathroom

Home is 30 years old. Screens in upstairs bathroom broke. Got replacement screens but need to fold window down to replace. Unfortunately the wood inside the home is overlapping around  a quarter inch and blocks the window from folding down. So I am unable to install new screens. Someone said just sand down the sides that are blocking until it folds down. I'm not sure if that's a good idea. Homebuilder made a mistake here. Probably one of a kind mistake.

Comment: No, seen that in several places... not sure if it is a Friday afternoon job or a "beer" lunch effect. You have to find a solution - sanding down might take a while but a small circular saw may work - depends on access...

Comment: What "wood"? Casing? Jamb extension? Please describe better or post photos.

Comment: I would not suggest modifying the framework without seeing the window. Not all windows fold. A photo would be helpful.

Comment: Is this something that could be done from outside from a ladder, staging or lift? And please [edit] to include pictures.

Comment: Can't answer without a picture or multiple pictures. What wood are you referring to? How is this wood attached? Is it part of the window or the trim around the window? How is it blocking the window?